# Get back Web page Likes

Tags: social-likes

I recently updated my website due to upgrades by my host (Go Daddy).

I put a script on my updated page for the like button.

My site had over 1900 likes. When I first launched the updates the social likes appeared as usual, but now it has gone to zero.

How do I get my likes back?

I need your assistance please, I have tried to delete the script and re-post it, but that did not help.

http://www.sandy-robson.com

Comment: We need to see your example code.  Remember to use a new line above and below your code, and to start each line with four spaces.

Comment: at top of page I have: <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

Comment: where I want the like button I have: <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.sandy-robson.com" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>

Comment: the button is there but my original likes that my site had have not appeared

Comment: I have figured out just now what the problem is...

Comment: my website home-page is now called: http://www.sandy-robson.com-home and before it was www.sandy-robson.com/Home_Page.html-Home Page

Comment: how do I fix the coding problem?

Comment: I think I have resolved this by using my old website homepage address to get the code for the plugin!  I am a novice at this.  Your comments helped me - THANKYOU!!!